# Can i place two AdMob ads on one page (Fixed Banner and scroll able Native Ad)

Tags: android, admob, policy, banner-ads, native-ads

I have an Activity that shows a Fixed banner that's located at the bottom of the screen and a Scroll able native ad that's inside my list view.

Is my implementation respect AdMob policy rules ?

I've already sow [this](http://Is%20it%20against%20rules%20of%20admob%20placing%20two%20ads%20on%20one%20app%20activity?), but my case is difrent here knowing that only 1 ad is fixed and the other is scroll able, but at the end i think they will all show at the same page just like this.

[image]

> The number of ads on a single page should not exceed one if the ad is fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, there should be a maximum of one ad on the top and one ad on the bottom, and both ads should not appear on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Look this thread:

http://forums.makingmoneywithandroid.com/advertising-networks/34763-native-ads-banners-admob-policy.html

Answer (score 0):

no, bro you cant,
other wise your account suspend i alredy suspend my account by this ads policy problem

Comment: why this cannot ya?